# how to change the Connected SharePoint site Settings Programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, jsom

I want to retrieve the "Connected SharePoint Site" Settings programmatically and also change the settings if they are different from my required criteria.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the settings page ? how do we do that via UI ?